# lapply function with arguments I want to pick from a dataframe with a loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, lapply

I'm still very new to R and haven't found any answer so far. Sorry to finally ask.

Edition with a quick example:
I want to compute a multidimensional development index based on South Africa Data.
My list is composed of individual information for each year, so basically df1 is about year 1 and df2 about year2.

```
df1<-data.frame(var1=c(1, 1,1), var2=c(0,0,1), var3=c(1,1,0))
df2<-data.frame(var1=c(1, 0,1), var2=c(1,0,1), var3=c(0,1,0))
mylist <-list (df1,df2)
```

You can find here a very simplified working index function:

```
myindex <- function(x, dimX, dimY){
    econ_i<- ( x[dimX]+  x[dimY] ) 
    return ( (1/length(econ_i))*sum(econ_i) )
    }
myindex(df1, "var2", "var3")
```

Then I have my dataframe of variables I want to use for my index

```
mydf <- data.frame(set1=c("var1", "var2"), set2=c("var2", "var3"))
```

I'm using a function to get arguments from database such as:

```
pick_values <-function(x){
    vect <-c()
    for(i in x){
    vect <- c(vect, i)
    }
    return(vect)
    }
```

I'd like to set up a lapply loop such that I apply my function for my list, for all sets of arguments in my dataframe. In other words, I'd like to compute my index for both years, with all sets of variables I can use. //end Edit

I've tried many unsuccessful things so far. For instance:

```
lapply(mylist, myindex, lapply(mydf,pick_values))
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Maybe use `mapply` which is good for iterating over multiple arguments? Or maybe rewrite `fun` to expect a `list(arg1, arg2)` as the second argument? It's hard to tell without a small reproducible example, with a couple rows of `data`, and an example `mylist`. It doesn't really seem like `pick_values` does anything useful, seems like `lapply(data, pick_values)` is an inefficient version of `as.list(data)`.

Comment: Thanks Gregor for your answer. I've edited my text with a quick example to make it far more easier to get.

Comment: Okay, to be clear you have 2 columns in `mydf` and 2 data frames in `mylist`, so you are expecting a list of  2*2 = 4 evaluations as a result?

Comment: Yes exactly ! :)

Comment: Do you want the results to be nested at all? For example, you could have a results list that has structure (a) `results = list(df1 = list(set1, set2), df2 = list(set1, set2))`, or (b) `list(set1 = list(df1, df2), set2 = (df1, df2))`, or (c) a flat structure `list(df1_set1, df1_set2, df2_set1, df2_set2)`

Comment: To answer your question very late, I'd like to get the results as a (b), so I have time series for each index, instead of a list of indexes for each year (what I have so far with your awesome method, though ^^)

Comment: Sorry to ask, but https://stackoverflow.com/users/903061/gregor have you seen my previous question ? :) Is there an easy way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I don't like your `mydf` name nor that it has factors, so I rename it `args` because it has function arguments and I set `stringsAsFactors = F`:

```
args <- data.frame(set1=c("var1", "var2"), set2=c("var2", "var3"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

We'll also write a wrapper for `myindex` that accepts a vector of arguments instead of `dimX` and `dimY`:

```
myindex2 = function(x, d) {
    myindex(x, d[1], d[2])
}
```

Then we can nest `lapply` like this:

```
lapply(mylist, function(m) lapply(args, myindex2, x = m))
# $df1
# $df1$set1
# [1] 4
#
# $df1$set2
# [1] 3
#
# 
# $df2
# $df2$set1
# [1] 4
#
# $df2$set2
# [1] 3
```

Comment: THanks a lot again, Gregor, that's really helpful.

Comment: That said, I don't understand how you nested lapply function works. I'm trying to find good tutorials about those nested functions ! :)

Comment: My outer apply applies a function to each item of `mylist`. What function do I apply? The anyonymous function `function(m) lapply(args, myindex2, x = m)`, and notice that the inner `lapply` *doesn't* apply across `m`, it applies to each element of `args`, and uses the current value of `m` as an argument. It's identical to a nested for loop if the outer loop were `for (m in mylist) { for (a in args) {myindex2(x = m, d = a) }}`, with a handy list container set up to catch the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I finally managed to figure out. But better still when properly explained :)

Comment: Your attempt didn't work because there was no nesting. You have `lapply(mylist, FUN = myindex, ... = lapply(mydf,pick_values))`, which is equivalent to `a = lapply(mydf, pick_values); for (m in mylist) {myindex(m, a)}`, and `a` just has all the args you want in different iterations lumped together.