# How to get in a specific order the results of an r lapply function with arguments from a dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, lapply

Following [a previous question I asked, I got an awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837411/lapply-function-with-arguments-i-want-to-pick-from-a-dataframe-with-a-loop).

**Here is a quick summary:**
 I want to compute a multidimensional development index based on South Africa Data for several years. My list is composed of individual information for each year, so basically df1 is about year 1 and df2 about year2.

```
df1<-data.frame(var1=c(1, 1,1), var2=c(0,0,1), var3=c(1,1,0))
df2<-data.frame(var1=c(1, 0,1), var2=c(1,0,1), var3=c(0,1,0))
mylist <-list (df1,df2)
```

var1 could be the stance on religion of each person, var2 how she voted in last national election, etc. In my very simple case, I have the data for 3 different persons each year.
From there, I compute an index based on a number of variables (not all of them)
You can find here a very simplified working index function, with only 2 of 3 variables, named dimX and dimY:

```
myindex <- function(x, dimX, dimY){
    econ_i<- ( x[dimX]+  x[dimY] ) 
    return ( (1/length(econ_i))*sum(econ_i) )
    }
myindex(df1, "var2", "var3")
```

and

```
myindex2 = function(x, d) {
    myindex(x, d[1], d[2])
}
```

Then I have my dataframe of variables I want to use for my index. I am trying to compute the index for several sets of variables.

```
args <- data.frame(set1=c("var1", "var2"), set2=c("var2", "var3"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I'd like to have the result as follows : (a)`list(set1 = list(df1, df2), set2 = (df1, df2))`instead of (b) `list(df1 = list(set1, set2), df2 = list(set1, set2))`.
Case (a) represents a time series, meaning I have a list of results of my indexes each year for only one set of variables. Case (b) is the opposite where I have the index results of one year for every set of variables. Each individual result should be a unique numeric value. Hence, I am expecting to get a list of 2 sublists df1 and df2, each sublist containing 3 numeric values.

I've been adviced to do use that great command:

```
lapply(mylist, function(m) lapply(args, myindex2, x = m))
```

It's working great, but I get the result in the "wrong" format, namely the second one (b) I showed.
How could I get the results ordered per set (i.e. case (a) as time series) instead of per year?

Thanks a lot for your help!

PJ

**EDIT**: I've managed to find a solution that doesn't answer the question, but still allows me to get my data in desired order.
Namely, I'm transforming my list of lists to a matrix that I simply transpose.

Comment: A couple of notes: the time series note you made there in the last line is vague. Also please provide more elaborate visuals describing what you want. You need to make your objective clear through the visuals. For example: what is the "wrong" format and what is "right" format? Make it easy as possible for the reader to understand what you are saying.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my post to make it as clear as possible. Don't hesitate to tell me if I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: I've got one question to ask before I or someone else answers your question. It's stated below.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer will be edited!**

Currently, your function `index()` does this

```
myindex <- function(x, dimX, dimY){
  econ_i<- ( x[dimX]+  x[dimY] ) 
  return ( (1/length(econ_i))*sum(econ_i) )
}
```

**Aren't you after this, however?**

```
myindex <- function(x, dimX, dimY){
  econ_i<- ( x[,dimX]+  x[,dimY] ) 
  return ( (1/length(econ_i))*sum(econ_i) )
}
```

The way you have it right now, `length(econ_i)` always returns 1 because `econ_i` is a `data.frame()` and not a vector. The length of a `data.frame()` is always 1, while the length of a vector is the number of elements within it.

Kindly note that here is what the output looks like in R.

```
df1["var1"]
  var1
1    1
2    1
3    1
```

returns a `data.frame()`

```
df1[,"var1"]
[1] 1 1 1
```

returns a vector.

I will adjust this post to answer your question when you respond. I think it's important to solve this part first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Actually, that's a very good point. I made a mistake in my example, but luckily it doesn't really affect my outcome since in my actual index, I'm using nrow() instead of length(). I've used both the x[dimX] and x[,dimX] with my data and I get the same result. Hence, I'd say that even though what you're pointing out is very accurate, per se, it is not really relevant for my actual issue.

Comment: What does index represent? I'm unsure what it's computing.

Comment: I'm answering with my actual index function to let you see what it is :)

Comment: I posted my actual index function. If I may provide additional informational, let me know, of course! I'm very grateful you're helping.

Answer (score 1):

If that may provide any help, [from this article](http://www.ferdi.fr/sites/www.ferdi.fr/files/idi/I15_relational%20Capability_web.pdf), here my actual index function:

```
RCI_a_3det <-function(x, econ1, econ2, econ3, perso1, perso2, perso3, civic1, civic2, civic3){ 

    econ_i<- (1/3) *( x[econ1]+  x[econ2] + x[econ3]) 
    perso_i<- (1/3)*( x[perso1] + x[perso2] + x[perso3]) 
    civic_i<- (1/3)*(x[civic1] + x[civic2] + x[civic3]) 

    daf <- data.frame(econ_i, perso_i, civic_i) 
    colnames(daf)<- c("econ_i", "perso_i", "civic_i") 
    df1 <- subset(daf, daf$econ_i !=1 & daf$perso_i !=1 & daf$civic_i!=1 )

    sum_xik <- (df1$econ_i + df1$perso_i + df1$civic_i)

    return ( 1/(3*nrow(df1)) * sum(sum_xik, na.rm=T))

    }
```

Edit:
x is a list of all personal information, for every variable and for every year. It is pretty large.
I am using 9 variables to compute this index, but I actually have 30 such variables in my data, so I have set up a dataframe of sets of variables I could use to compute this index. This is the equivalent of my args df in the simple example. I am actually using 200 such combinations.

Comment: Being in France I'm off to bed. I'll answer anything more tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, nice to know some context. It was just my curiosity peaking through.